# Incompatibility between amsrefs and memoir?

Tags: memoir, incompatibility, amsrefs

I am having trouble trying to use `amsrefs` together with the `memoir` class.  Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsrefs}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

LaTeX gives me the error `LaTeX Error: Command \bibsection already defined.`

Googling around, I found only [this](http://compgroups.net/comp.text.tex/amsrefs-and-memoir-problem/1918629) question from 2005, which appears identically on several different forums.  I don't really understand the solution proposed there.

If it matters, I am using TeXLive 2012 and I just downloaded the `amsrefs` package from CTAN, so everything is pretty up to date.

Has anybody run into this before?  Is there any way to get around it?

---

Resolution: the suggestion in the comments worked.  Adding `\let\bibsection\relax` immediately before loading `amsrefs` allows `amsrefs` to 
redefine the `\bibsection` command.

Comment: a hack to get round it is to use `\let\bibsection\relax` just before you load `amsrefs`... not sure if it's *the* way to go or not...

Comment: I don't know how much compatible `amsrefs` is with `memoir`. However, since the latter uses `\bibsection` in the `thebibliography` environment, which `amsrefs` redefines, the path suggested by @cmhughes might be sufficient.

Comment: `amsrefs` has, to the best of my knowledge, not been tested with `memoir`; certainly it hasn't been so tested here at ams, and i think isn't likely to be.  but the cited suggestion (from 2005) looks plausible, and worth a try.

Comment: @barbarabeeton It was a very interesting project; but probably switching to `biblatex` is the best choice, nowadays.

Comment: @egreg -- the only problem with that is that ams is not likely to support `biblatex` any time soon.  (there's too great an investment in `bibtex` and `amsrefs`.)  if any `biblatex` code is submitted to ams publications, it will be rekeyed -- in `amsrefs`, which i understand will not be returned to the author.

Comment: Another option (well, it is basically the same that appears in the 2005 suggestion linked) is to use the `savesym` package:     `\documentclass{memoir}
    \usepackage{savesym}
    \savesymbol{bibsection}
    \usepackage{amsrefs}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sub>(CW from comments)</sub>

It seems that removing the definition of `\bibsection` made by `memoir` before loading `amsrefs` can solve the issue:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\let\bibsection\relax
\usepackage{amsrefs}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\end{document}
```